# How to use array values outside foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

How can I use an array values outside a foreach loop in Laravel 5.4?
Here is the code :

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('keyword');
        $category = $request->input('category');
        $catkeywords = array(DB::table('keywords')->pluck($category));
        foreach ($catkeywords as $catkeyword) {
            $string = implode(',',$catkeyword);
        }
        echo $string;
    }
```

I don't know why it doesn't work !

I just want the returned keywords from database to **combine** them with some text and to use for some **API queries**.

In other words, I want the list of keywords **outside of the loop**.

For using in an API query like this :

```
http://api-url/query?id=domain1.com,domain2.com,domain3.com
```

`$catkeywords` returns a **json** formatted list of keywords.

Now I want to **combine these keywords with a user-inputted value** and **add a ".com" suffix**,
then **separate them using commas** and use them on query url as a variable.
P.S : I'm using `guzzlehttp` for sending requests to the API. So it should be placed on :

`'DomainList' => $domainlist`

How can I do that ?

Comment: `$string` inside your `foreach loop` will replace its value in every loop. So, you need to concatenate using `.=` . Remember (dot) before equals to.

Comment: is that return any error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using laravel, you should consider taking advantages of their collections:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-implode

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('keyword');
    $category = $request->input('category');
    $catkeywords = DB::table('keywords')->implode($category, ',');
    echo $catkeywords;
}
```

Laravel collections have a command for imploding the array, so there's no need to use pluck and loop through the array unless you plan on doing other operations on the data too.

**EDIT:** Based on updated question, it sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('keyword');
    $category = $request->input('category');
    $catkeywords = DB::table('keywords')->pluck($category); //You don't need to wrap this in an array()
    $keywords = []; //Create a holding array
    foreach ($catkeywords as $catkeyword) {
        $keywords[] = $catkeyword . '.com'; //Push the value to the array
    }
    echo implode(',', $keywords); //Then implode the edited values at the end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try do that

```
   public function index(Request $request)
   {
       $name = $request->input('keyword');
       $string = '';
       $category = $request->input('category');
       $catkeywords = array(DB::table('keywords')->pluck($category));
       foreach ($catkeywords as $catkeyword) {
           $string .= implode(',',$catkeyword);
       }
       echo $string;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use pluck() method then it return array of given name 
so you dont have need to use foreach loop

just use

```
$catkeywords = array(DB::table('keywords')->pluck($category));
echo implode(',',$catkeyword);
```